# Variable not updating in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to calculate `+1` to variable `cell2` after every step of my script. This is my script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();


  var cell1 = 'D';
  var cell2 = '2';
  var cell = cell1 + cell2;

  cell2 ++;
  cell2 ++;
  cell2 ++;
}
```

Now after running this script, `cell2` is `5` (as expected). But as you can see in the debugger below, `cell` is still `D2` instead of expected the `D5`. **It was never updated**.

[image: debugger screenshot]

**How can I keep `cell` updated without having to declare it again after every step?** I'm new to Google Apps Script and didn't find a similar problem.

Comment: The `+` operator (when used on at least one string) concatenates the two operands together and creates a new string. The result is completely separate to the variables it was derived from. This has nothing to do with Google Apps Script, it's how JavaScript itself works. How you can make it working depends a bit on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ivar It's really just a step counter. It should count +1 to the counter after every step and in the end I have the total number of steps made.

Comment: Then do the string concatenating at the end after running all the steps?

Comment: @Ivar sorry, I meant that the concatenating has to happen after every step. I want it to go: D2, D3, D4, D5... in between every step :)

Comment: You could do something like `const getStep = () => cell1 + cell2;` and then call `getStep()` to get the step depending on the current values of `cell1` and `cell2`. There might be better solutions but those depend on the context.

Comment: Based on your context are you by any chance trying to read ranges from a spreadsheet by doing that? If so, could you provide a bit more info on the context of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @FernandoLara In the end, I want to paste a range of cells from old sheets to the new one. Since the range is not always the same, I want to count the cells, so I know the position of the next empty cell. (So I can continue to paste there)

Comment: @verfluecht Is the size of the range always the same? Could you provide an example with some sample data? I think this can be easily achieved but a script would need to be adapted to your specific use case.